# How do I combine these two spatial queries for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, geospatial

I have two queries, one that returns the top 10 closest locations:

```
            DECLARE @center GEOGRAPHY

            SET @center = geography::Point(@Latitude, @Longitude, 4326)

            SELECT TOP 10
                [Physical_Address_Street]
                , [Physical_Address_Local]
                , [Physical_Address_State]
                , [Physical_Address_Zip]
                , [Phone_Number]
            FROM Gas_Stations
            WHERE Location_Type = 1
            ORDER BY @center.STDistance(Location) ASC
```

And then another which will get the distance to a lat and long that is passed in

```
            SELECT Location.STDistance(geography::Point(51, -2, 4326)) * 0.00062137119 
            FROM [MY_DB].[dbo].[Gas_Station]
```

These both query the same table so how can I combine these and also get the distance of each of the ten points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  TOP 10
        *,
        geography::Point(51, -2, 4326).STDistance(location) * 0.00062137119
FROM    gas_stations
WHERE   location_type = 1
ORDER BY
        @center.STDistance(location) ASC
```

Comment: As soon as I modified my query to that when I open the webservice that runs this query I get a website cannot display page.

Comment: @MarkBasler: you did try it first in SSMS, didn't you?

Comment: I just tried it there and I get invalid columns... I am going to add to your answer what I put in